# Why EF Core 3.1 StringLength Attribute doubles SQL column length

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, string-length, nvarchar, ef-core-3.1

Am using EF core 3.1 Code first approach. When i specify `[StringLength(51)]` for a data model param, the equivalent SQL column length is specified as `nvarchar(102)`. Why is it getting doubled?
What should i do to get same maximum length in SQL column too?

Note : MS SQL Server is my backend.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the string length and not the data size? Data size should be 102 as each char takes 1 byte.

Comment: @Igor So, you mean character length is still 51 in SQL and data size is 102 as each char takes 2 bytes right?

Comment: @Igor The Length param in SQL table schema shows 102

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Igor for your comment. My bad, it was having same length in SQL also. Doubling is for size in bytes which is for every char it is two bytes. The below query is helpful in understanding it, Hence posting it as answer that helps someone like me.

````
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH       
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME='Table_Name'```
````

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use

```
[MaxLength(51)] // nvarchar(51)
public string Email{ get; set; }
```

Comment: i need Nvarchar type. When i specify nvarchar -  migration is not allowed.

Comment: for nvarchar - StringLength need not be specified, however the length in SQL is still 102 which is double the value of [Column(TypeName = "NVARCHAR(51)")]

Comment: Did you try Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(MAX)")]  without StringLength

Comment: i need a fixed size for that column. The default itself is nvarchar(max).

Comment: I edited my answer, please check the new code to specify a fixed max length to nvarchar you should use MaxLength instead of StringLength

Comment: MaxLength is resulting in the same issue :(. Doubling the length.

Comment: when you perform add-migration, is the length specified in the generated migration file is the double of you already set?